# File element on context menu is undefined - why?

Tags: angular, typescript, contextmenu

I trying to rebuild my `context menu` (part 2 today). Now i have issue with undefined value of mu file element. I can't delete, rename or anything because of it.

HTML

```
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let element of fileElements" (click)="navigate(element)" (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, element)" >
        [...]
    </mat-list-item>
[...]
<div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed"
    [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
    [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenuTag">
</div>
<mat-menu #contextMenuTag="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-item>
    <div *ngFor="let element of contextMenu">
      <button *ngIf="!element.seperator" mat-menu-item (click)="callFunction(element, item)">
        {{element.name}}
      </button>
      <mat-divider *ngIf="element.seperator"></mat-divider>
    </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

ts

```
public callFunction(menu: MenuElement, file?: FileElement): void {
    console.log(file);  // <-- UNDEFINED THERE
    switch(menu.action) {
      case 'delete': {
        this.deleteElement(file);
        break;
      }
      [...]
    }
  }

private deleteElement(element: FileElement): void {
    this.elementRemoved.emit(element);
  }
```

Before i changed my first implementation of UGLY `context menu`, delete action works. I think is fail at passing by `(contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, element)"` to mat-menu on bottom. Maybe somebody know the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is the forgotten event that the variable didn't name `item`.It seems like modified with sample code that you would found out the `matMenuTriggerData` would bind the data to your `ng-template`.

```html
<div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed"
    [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
    [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenuTag"
    [matMenuTriggerData]="{item:theitemfromyourcode}" >
</div>
```

In Addition, keep in mind to set the `let-item` to your variable, the variable would be defined in ts somehow. Otherwise, the item would bind to `$implict`.

```html
<ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item">
[...]
</ng-template>
```